# ALOHA network simulation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, simulation

I'm currently studying the book 
From Algorithms to Z-Scores: Probabilistic and Statistical Modelling in Computer Science

In the first chapter of the book the ALOHA network protocol is introduced as an example of probabilistic modelling. I decided to write a python simulation and run some tests to check the overall performance of a network of this type (latency, successful transmission/accuracy).

```
import random
class aloha():  
    '''
    Aloha network simulation. 
    Each node tries to send into a single channel. It generates a message (becomes active) 
    with probability q. Then it tries to send the message into the channel with probability
    p. If more than one nodes try to send, a collision occurs resulting to failure, otherwise 
    transmission is successful.
    '''

    def __init__(self, nodes,p_send,q_generate,epochs):
        # number of nodes
        self.nodes = nodes

        # probability that an active node will send the generated message
        self.p_send = p_send

        # probability that a node will generate a message
        self.q_generate = q_generate

        # number of time steps to simulate
        self.epochs = epochs

        # list with the state of each node, initially all inactive
        self.states = [False for i in range(self.nodes)]

        # list of latencies for each node 
        self.latencies = [0 for i in range(self.nodes)]

        # list of transmission outcomes. True for success
        self.result = []

    def message_generation(self):
        '''
        Helper function to check message generation
        '''
        for i in range(len(self.states)):
            # need only to check for inactive nodes
            if self.states[i] == False:
                if random.random()<=self.q_generate:
                    self.states[i] = True


    def transmission(self):
        senders = []
        actives = []

        # gather the indices of all active nodes
        for i in range(len(self.states)):
            if self.states[i] == True:
                actives.append(i)

        # check if an active node will try to send
        for i in range(len(actives)):
            if random.random()<=self.p_send:
                senders.append(actives[i])

        #print('Towards the end of this epoch the nodes that try to send are ' + str(len(senders)))
        #print(senders)
        # If more than one try to send we have a collision that results in transmission failure
        if len(senders) > 1:
            self.result.append(False)
            # so any active node experiences latency
            for active in actives:
                self.latencies[active] += 1
        else:
            # If none wants to send then certainly we don't experience failure
            if (len(senders) == 0):
                self.result.append(True)
                # but we might experience latency 
                for active in actives:
                    self.latencies[active] += 1
            else:
                # Success. Only one node tries to send
                self.states[senders[0]] = False
                # and all other active nodes experience latency again
                actives.remove(senders[0])
                for active in actives:
                    self.latencies[active] +=1 
                self.result.append(True)
                #print('Thus resulting in successful transmission.')



    def simulate(self):
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            #print('At the start of epoch number ' + str(i) + ' the states are')
            #print(self.states)
            self.message_generation()
            #print('At the middle of epoch number ' + str(i) + ' the states are')
            #print(self.states)
            self.transmission()
            #print('At the end of epoch number ' + str(i) + ' the states are')
            #print(self.states)
```

The commented print statements were put for debug purposes. I apologize if it makes the code uglier. I'm on a transition from python 2 to python 3 so I'd like pointers to stuff that can be done more easily in the latter and overall comments on efficiency.

Below is the code for testing of the protocol.

```
'''
Code to test the accuracy of the network (#successful_transfers/#epochs)
and latency for various values of p
'''
q=0.5
p=0.05
n=3
e=500
accuracy = []
avg_latency = []
percentage_of_latents = []
while p<1:
    x = aloha(n,p,q,e)
    x.simulate()
    accuracy.append( x.result.count(True)/e )
    latents = [latency for latency in x.latencies if latency!=0]
    avg_latency.append(sum(latents)/len(latents))
    p += 0.1
print(accuracy)
print(avg_latency)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Lists of the same primitive elements

Instead of this:

> ```
> # list with the state of each node, initially all inactive
> self.states = [False for i in range(self.nodes)]
>
> # list of latencies for each node 
> self.latencies = [0 for i in range(self.nodes)]
> ```

A more compact and simpler way to create lists of the same primitive elements:

```
# list with the state of each node, initially all inactive
self.states = [False] * self.nodes

# list of latencies for each node 
self.latencies = [0] * self.nodes
```

Just be mindful that this technique is useful with primitive elements only.

#### Use boolean expressions directly

This is not natural writing style:

> ```
> if self.states[i] == False:
>     # ...
>
> if self.states[i] == True:
>     # ...
> ```

This is the recommended way:

```
if not self.states[i]:
    # ...

if self.states[i]:
    # ...
```

#### Non-empty lists are truthy, empty lists are falsy

Instead of this:

> ```
> if (len(senders) == 0):
>     # ...
> ```

You can write:

```
if not senders:
    # ...
```

#### Use list comprehensions

Instead of this:

> ```
> actives = []
>
> # gather the indices of all active nodes
> for i in range(len(self.states)):
>     if self.states[i] == True:
>         actives.append(i)
> ```

You can write more compactly using a list comprehension like this:

```
# gather the indices of all active nodes
actives = [i for i in range(len(self.states)) if self.states[i]]
```

You can do similarly for `senders`.

#### Iterating over indexes and values of a list

`enumerate` is very convenient when iterating over list indexes and values.
For example instead of this:

> ```
> # gather the indices of all active nodes
> actives = [i for i in range(len(self.states)) if self.states[i]]
> ```

You can write more compactly and naturally like this:

```
# gather the indices of all active nodes
actives = [i for i, state in enumerate(self.states) if state]
```

#### Coding style

Python has an official style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
I suggest to follow it.